# How do you access a specific fragment in FragPagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter

I currently have a FragmentPagerAdapter that creates new instances of each Fragment through getItem(int position) method. However, I'm not quite sure how to access the Fragment I created again. Is there a public method that another class can call from the FragmentPagerAdapter to select the specific Fragment created at, for example, position 12?

```
public class ChannelFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private int numChannels;
    public ChannelFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Activity context, PatientSettings user) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
        numChannels = user.channelsLimit;
        for(int i = 1; i <= numChannels; i++){
            channelTabs.add("" + i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return channelTabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        //new instance is a static factory for creating Fragment objects
        return ChannelFragment.newInstance(position + 1, this);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        //generate title based on item position
        //return tabTitles[position];
        return  channelTabs.get(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide us your code?

Comment: I will update my question with relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are trying to create a viewpager that supports more than 5 fragments, so using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is better.

Back to your question, using Fragment tag and get in through `findFragmentByTag()`. In your adapter, store them in a list, and get them whenever you need.

```
public class ChannelFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private int numChannels;
    Map<Integer, String> tags;

    public ChannelFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Activity context, PatientSettings user) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
        numChannels = user.channelsLimit;
        tags = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= numChannels; i++) {
            channelTabs.add("" + i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return channelTabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        //new instance is a static factory for creating Fragment objects
        return ChannelFragment.newInstance(position + 1, this);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        //generate title based on item position
        //return tabTitles[position];
        return channelTabs.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment createdFragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        tags.put(position, createdFragment.getTag());
        // ... save the tags somewhere so you can reference them later
        return createdFragment;
    }
}
```

Note: Please check null when using `findFragmentByTag()`, your fragment could be destroyed or replaced.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I'm curious as the what is specifically different in how FragmentStatePagerAdapter and  FragmentPagerAdapter organize/use the fragments contained within them.

Comment: Think in simple way, if you want to create a lot of fragments (like reading books app), use FragmentStatePagerAdapter